# C++ - same static method for any type of a template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have 2 templated classes, Matrix4x4t and Vector3t, and a number of static methods in Matrix4x4t that operate on them both. Matrix4x4t is defined as follows, with one of said static methods included:

```
template <class T>
class Matrix4x4t
{
public:
    T values[16];
    ...
    template <class W, class U, class V> 
    static void multiply3x3Vector3(const Matrix4x4t<W> &m, 
                                   const Vector3t<U> &columnVector,       
                                   Vector3t<V> &result);
    ...
};
```

The idea of `multiply3x3Vector3` is to take any possible type of matrix (m) and vector (columnVector), perform multiplication, then store the result in a vector (result), converting to it's type if different. This works well and allows me to do the following:

```
Matrix4x4t<double> matd;
Vector3t<float> vec3f(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
Vector3t<int> resulti;

Matrix4x4t<float>::multiply3x3Vector3(matd, vec3f, resulti); //This works
Matrix4x4t<double>::multiply3x3Vector3(matd, vec3f, resulti); //So does this
```

The issue is that if I'm understanding correctly, the compiler will create 2 separate definitions of `multiple3x3Vector3`, one for `Matrix4x4t<int>` and another for `Matrix4x4t<double>`, even though they take the same types and do the same thing. It's probably also unclear for the user why they need to use a specific type of `Matrix4x4t` for each call when they produce the same result, and it would be nicer if they could just call:

```
 Matrix4x4t::multiply3x3Vector3(matd, vec3f, resulti);
```

The solution to both is to make `multiple3x3Vector3` a function separate from the class itself, but I like having it inside the scope of `Matrix4x4t`. I could have static methods that simply call an external function, but before I go this route I thought I'd ask if there is something I'm missing that would solve the two issues and let me keep the method inside the class?

Comment: I find it very confusing that these functions are members of the matrix classes.  I think having them as free functions would be much cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's one option to make the requested  `Matrix4x4t::multiply3x3Vector3(matd, vec3f, resulti)` syntax work correctly:

```
template <class T=void>
class Matrix4x4t;

template <>
class Matrix4x4t<void>
{
public:
    template <class W, class U, class V> 
    static void multiply3x3Vector3(const Matrix4x4t<W> &m, 
                                   const Vector3t<U> &columnVector,       
                                   Vector3t<V> &result);
    ...
};

template <class T>
class Matrix4x4t // perhaps inherit Matrix4x4t<void>
{
public:
    T values[16];
    ...
};
```

But as 5gon12eder commented, putting these associated functions in the namespace and letting them be found via Koenig lookup is even nicer and more consistent with accepted C++ style.

Comment: Excellent, I've learned something new today (Koenig lookup). I'll accept this answer as not only did it recommend a better alternative (which I'll use), it also answered the question. Thanks!